# Removing double quotes and spaces in an XML tag in linux

Tags: xml, linux, text-processing

I would like to remove spaces and quotes from the value of XML tag `<ns:tag2>` in my XML file on Linux(spaces to be removed only for this tag not other places).

Sample XML content looks like below.

```
<ns:tag1>
    <ns:tag2>Abcdef qwert/denn+hkg kmknn xyz""""""""""</ns:tag2> 
</ns:tag1>
```

But I need the file to be written as shown below.

```
<ns:tag1>
    <ns:tag2>Abcdefqwert/denn+hkgkmknnxyz</ns:tag2> 
</ns:tag1>
```

I have seen the solution at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274736/remove-string-with-spaces-and-quotes-from-xml-file and tried using sed command to remove the quotes but no luck.

```
sed  's/ ""//g'  temp.xml
```

Please suggest me right syntax for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is looking for the exact string `""`, not any of those characters. Use the `[]` character set operator to match any of a set of characters.

```
sed 's/[ "]//g' temp.xml
```

However, this will remove *all* spaces, not just the spaces in tag values. So the result will be:

```
<ns:tag1>
<ns:tag2>Abcdefqwert/denn+hkgkmknnxyz</ns:tag2> 
</ns:tag1>
```

And if you have any tags with attributes, it will remove the spaces between the attributes, e.g.

```
<ns:tag1 attr1="foo" attr2="1 2">
```

will become

```
<ns:tag1attr1="foo"attr2="12">
```

It's probably not feasible to do what you want just with regular expressions. I recommend using a tool for parsing XML, such as `xmlstarlet`. You can extract the values into variables, remove the spaces and quotes, then generate new XML with the results.